# Laravel 5 Eager Loading not working

Tags: php, loading, laravel-5, eager

I look at many search results with this trouble but i can`t get it to work.

The **User Model**:

```
<?php namespace Module\Core\Models;

class User extends Model {

(...)

protected function Person() {
    return $this->belongsTo( 'Module\Core\Models\Person', 'person_id' );
}

(...)
```

And the **Person Model**:

```
<?php namespace Module\Core\Models;

class Person extends Model {

(...)

protected function User(){
    return $this->hasOne('Module\Core\Models\User', 'person_id');
}

(...)
```

Now, if i use User::find(1)->Person->first_name its work. I can get the Persons relations from the User Model.

But.. **User::with('Person')->get()** fails with a ***Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Person()***

What im doing wrong? i need a collection of all the users with their Person information.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem but you should declare your relationship methods as `public`

Comment: and... that its the solution.. Thanks lukasgeiter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the relationship methods as `public`.

Why is that? Let's take a look at the `with()` method:

```
public static function with($relations)
{
    if (is_string($relations)) $relations = func_get_args();

    $instance = new static;

    return $instance->newQuery()->with($relations);
}
```

Since the method is called from a static context it can't just call `$this->Person()`. Instead it creates a new instance of the model and creates a query builder instance and calls `with` on that and so on. In the end the relationship method has to be accessible from *outside* the model. That's why the visibility needs to be `public`.